# Python Isinstance Function exception handling error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the isinstance() function below to check if the cells along a dataframe column are strings. However, I'm getting the following error:

KeyError: 13900

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

The code is below.

```
df1= pd.read_csv('FED001_072321_07.CSV', header=0, index_col = None)
import os
g=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for file in g:
    df= pd.read_csv(file, header=0, index_col = None)
    ipt=df.iloc[:,-2]
    ipt=ipt.dropna()
    for i in ipt:
            if isinstance(ipt[i], String)==False:
                sum=sum+ipt[i] 
                j=j+1
```

Comment: This is probably the wrong way to approach the problem. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The column has a mix of strings and numerical values. I want to go through the column and only extract the numerical values and ignore the strings.

Comment: Sounds good. So you want to take the sum of all the numerical values in the second-to-last column of each dataframe?

Comment: yup! that's right

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. It sounds like the data model of your CSV files might be interfering with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what your goal is, this may do what is wanted.

```py
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('FED001_072321_07.CSV', header=0, index_col=None)
sum_ = 0

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0, index_col=None)
    sum_ += df.iloc[:, -2].dropna().where(np.isreal).astype(float).sum()
```

From the sound of it, some of your columns have different types within the same column. Much of this logic is unnecessary if each column `df.iloc[:, -2]` can be assumed to be all floats.